# Address a group, then direct a message to a particular person

Tags: letter-writing

Example:

To all whom it may concern, *(this is a letter to a group)*

*Body of the message directed to the entire group here*

*Concluding that, direct a message to a specific person, for an acknowledgment or to show gratitude*

How should I go about the second part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer in a sample scenario:

> To all whom it may concern,
>
> Get ready for Saturday's event! We'll have 200 employees present and food catered from nearby restaurants. Make sure to spread the word to friends and family.
>
> Thank you to everyone for helping plan this event. Specifically, Jackie, thank you for spearheading this event, agreeing to donate auction items, and being a team cheerleader.

Comment: I edited your answer to replace the code markup with quote markup. It's more accepted to use quote markup for text, and leave code markup for, well, code. ;) The problem with code markup is that it doesn't adjust dynamically to fit everybody's screen, and can result in some unfriendly horizontal scrollbars.